# Static method, Abstract method, Interface method comparison?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-3.0

When I choose these methods? I can not decide which one I must prefer or when will i use one of them? which one give best performance?

### First Type Usage

```
public abstract class _AccessorForSQL
{
   public virtual bool Save(string sp, ListDictionary ld, CommandType cmdType);
   public virtual bool Update();
   public virtual bool Delete();
   public virtual DataSet Select();
}

class GenAccessor : _AccessorForSQL
{
    DataSet ds;
    DataTable dt;
    public override bool Save(string sp, ListDictionary ld, CommandType cmdType)
    {
    }

    public override bool Update()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool Delete()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override DataSet Select()
    {
        DataSet dst = new DataSet();
        return dst;
    }
}
```

### Second Type Usage

Also I can write it below codes:

```
public class GenAccessor
{
     public Static bool Save()
     { 
     }

     public Static bool Update()
     {
     }

     public Static bool Delete()
     {
     }
}
```

### Third Type Usage

Also I can write it below codes:

```
public interface IAccessorForSQL
{
    bool Delete();
    bool Save(string sp, ListDictionary ld, CommandType cmdType);
    DataSet Select();
    bool Update();
}

public class _AccessorForSQL : IAccessorForSQL
{
    private DataSet ds;
    private DataTable dt;

    public virtual bool Save(string sp, ListDictionary ld, CommandType cmdType)
    {            
    }
}
```

I can use first one  below usage:

```
GenAccessor gen = New GenAccessor();
gen.Save();
```

I can use second one below usage:

```
GenAccessor.Save();
```

Which one do you prefer? When will I use them? which time i need override method? which time I need static method?

Comment: The best way to learn is to actually write some programs and implement all that you think you have learned. Along the way you will grasp the detail and understand it much better than anyone could explain. You never 'need' static method, or interface or abstract method. But over time you will come to understand the purpose of each of it. That is how I come to understand all these 'details' btw..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

static methods are for methods which are independent of object state. Typically I would use them for utility methods and pure mathematical kind of functions. e.g. computeAverage(int[] values);

abstract/interface methods are pretty much the same thing. interface methods have the feel of pure contract. abstract methods are more version tolerant. If you have a contract and it can possibly have different implementations I would go with these.

static methods are more performant because they don't need to do virtual table lookup.

Comment: I agree with this explanation. And to answer directly to your question I would always prefer your first approach.

Comment: Why do you prefer first approach Somos?